# How can i solve this gcm error?

Tags: google-cloud-messaging

Please, I don't know where is the problem. My onReceive function doesn't work. The GmIntentService extend WakefulBroadcastReceiver... so the onReceive is not called! Here is my code (manifest) : if someone can help me......

```
    package="list.test.com.testnotification">

    <!-- Permission -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission andr`enter code here`oid:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />

    <permission
        android:name="list.test.com.testnotification.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />
    <uses-permission android:name="list.test.com.testnotification.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
    <!-- -->

Thanks in advance!
```

Comment: This manifest doesn't show anything. What is the error? You may want to show the code for your `onReceive` and how you create your [`BroadcastReceiver`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html). If that's all your manifest has, then you're definitely missing the receiver declaration.

Comment: I'd also suggest you use GcmListenerService, see here:https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/start